# tkinter- Passing entry widget value to another class

Tags: python, tkinter

I have adapted this code from an earlier question which neatly keeps a navigation frame but changes content frames depending on which button is pressed.  The login page has an entry widget. I want to transfer its value ("Paul" say) to the Play Game frame so it say "This is the game page Paul" for example. With this particular set up I don't know how to achieve it if anyone can help.

```
import tkinter as tk

class Page(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

    def show(self):
        self.lift()

    

class Page1(Page):
   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       
       Page.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
       
       label = tk.Label(self, text="This is the log in page ")
       username=tk.Entry(self)
      
       label.pack(side="top", pady=30, fill="both")
       username.pack()
       

class Page2(Page):
   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       Page.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

       label = tk.Label(self, text="This is the register page")
       label.pack(side="top", pady=30,fill="both")

class Page3(Page):
   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       
       
       Page.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
       label = tk.Label(self, text="This is the game page ") #+user
       label.pack(side="top",pady=30, fill="both")

class MainView(tk.Frame):
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        
        p1 = Page1(self)
        p2 = Page2(self)
        p3 = Page3(self)
        
        buttonframe = tk.Frame(self)
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        buttonframe.pack(side="left", fill="x", expand=False)
        buttonframe.configure(bg="red")
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        
        p1.place(in_=container, x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
        p2.place(in_=container, x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
        p3.place(in_=container, x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)

        b1 = tk.Button(buttonframe, text="Log In", width=8, command=p1.lift)
        b2 = tk.Button(buttonframe, text="Register",width=8, command=p2.lift)
        b3 = tk.Button(buttonframe, text="Play Game",width=8, command=p3.lift)

        b1.pack(padx=10,pady=10)
        b2.pack(padx=10,pady =10)
        b3.pack(padx=10,pady=10)

        p1.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    root = tk.Tk()
    main = MainView(root)
    main.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.wm_geometry("400x400")
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You need to keep a reference to the `tk.Entry` and all of the `Page` objects. Instead of `username=tk.Entry(self)` use `self.username = tk.Entry(self)`. That way you can later access it using `self.username` and you can get the contents of the `tk.Entry` using `self.username.get()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide a mechanism where each page can access the others. You also need to make sure that the data you need to access is available as an instance attribute.

### The Controller

Typically, the former is done through what is commonly called a *controller*. In this case that would be `MainView`, or a new class. Since `MainView` is responsible for creating the pages, it can also be responsible for giving access to each of the pages, which it can do by saving references to them when they are created.

It looks something like this:

```
class MainView(tk.Frame):
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ...            
        self.p1 = Page1(self)
        self.p2 = Page2(self)
        self.p3 = Page3(self)
        ...
```

### Using the controller in each page

The pages are being given a reference to `MainView` instance, so they can use that to get the data they need. It would look something like this:

```
class Page1(Page):
   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
   
       Page.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
   
       self.controller = args[0]
       ...
       self.username=tk.Entry(self)
       ...
```

When you repeat that pattern in every page, then every page has access to every other page via the controller: `self.controller.p1`, `self.controller.p2`, etc. And with that, `Page3` can access the username of `Page1` with something like `self.controller.p1.username`.

That is a basic mechanism for sharing data between separate objects.

### Constraints

Be aware that at the time you create page 3, the user will not have had a chance to fill in the username so the username will be empty. You'll have to add some logic to know when the user has logged in.

A simple solution to that problem is to give each page a `show` method. The `show` method is responsible for lifting the page and for updating it's widgets. It might look something like this:

```
class Page3(Page):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Page.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.controller = args[0]
        self.label = tk.Label(self, text="")
        self.label.pack(side="top",pady=30, fill="both")

    def show(self):
        user = self.controller.p1.username.get()
        self.label.configure(text=f"This is the game page for {user}")
        self.lift()
```

You then need to modify your buttons to call the `show` method:

```
b1 = tk.Button(..., command=self.p1.show)
b2 = tk.Button(..., command=self.p2.show)
b3 = tk.Button(..., command=self.p3.show)
```

### Summary

Having a controller is a convenient way to coordinate communication between objects. Instead of every object having to be directly linked with all of the other objects, they only need a reference to the controller. The controller then becomes the only object that has a direct connection to every other widget.

This isn't the best implementation of the view/controller pattern, but hopefully, it gives an idea of the basic concept.

Comment: Thank you both for your answer and Bryan for your full explanation which works. Brilliant! I would not have understood to add  the line, self.controller = args[0].  I guess from reading your other posts that a better way would be to create a class that saves shared data in a list?